# How to do a rolling sum in BigQuery for groups of weeks?

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the following table, which contains two columns: date and total_visits (website visits). I need to compute two new variables (rolling sums).

1. Column_A: A rolling sum for each day. For each day, I have to present the sum of the total visits from the last 14 days (without considering the current day). Of course, the first 14 days in this table can not have this value due to the fact there are not enough previous days to compute this value.
2. Column_B: A rolling sum for each day. For each day, I have to present the sum of the total visits considering the days between 4 weeks and 2 weeks before the current day. This means, for example, for 2019-01-29, the value we should be seeing is the sum of the total visits between 2021-01-01 and 2021-01-14. Of course, the first 28 days in the table won't have values for this column due to the fact there are no enough data to compute the value.

The next table is an example:

[image]

I currently have a solution in SQL (Workbench), but I need to apply this for a database store in GCP and there are syntax differences that I have not been able to understand. Any hint? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  if(dense_rank() over win <= 14, null, sum(total_visits) over rolling_last_14_day) as total_last_14_day,
  if(dense_rank() over win <= 28, null, sum(total_visits) over rolling_between_4_and_2_weeks_ago) as total_between_4_and_2_weeks_ago
from `project.dataset.table`
window win as (order by unix_date(date)),
  rolling_last_14_day as (win range between 14 preceding and 1 preceding),
  rolling_between_4_and_2_weeks_ago as (win range between 28 preceding and 15 preceding)
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have data on every day, just use a window frame:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (order by date) >= 14
             then sum(total_visits) over (order by date rows between 13 preceding and current row)
        end) as total_14_day,
       (case when row_number() over (order by date) >= 28
             then sum(total_visits) over (order by date rows between 27 preceding and 14 preceding)
        end) as total_14_day
from t;
```